# First(and not second) child of parent div ,take the remaining width

Tags: html, css

I am trying ,to do the following:

**(1st sentence)**: 
By using only html and css, have a parent div in which the second child will take 200px of the left most area of the browser ,while the first child will take the remaining width of the browser.

**(1st question)** :
Is that possible?

I am interested of this html children order because I am trying to accomplish this :

**(2nd sentence)** :
When the browser gets in portrait mode, the layout should be get changed (via media query)  with the left most child(and the one with the fixed width) gone below the right most child(that was taking the remaining width of browser).

**(2nd question)**:If the **(1st sentence)** is not possible which is the simplest way to accomplish the **(2nd sentence)**?

Comment: Make 1-2 pictures in paint or something to understand better your needs. Also add some details there, wich one is parent and wich one is child.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.2ndChild{
width: 200px;
float: left;
}
```

1st child will automatically float right to the 1st child and take the rest of the space.

Comment: no it won't the first child will never float arround the second one. the third would...

Comment: It seems that this approach doesn't work (please see http://jsfiddle.net/aMzy7/5/ ) unless you mean something else.

Answer (score 0):

**(1st question)** Not with pure css. It would work if you want the first child to have a fixed width (using float and width on the first and then overflow: hidden on the second element. But setting the width for the second child will never ever have any influence on an element, that appears before or above that one in the dom tree. Sorry...

**(2nd question)** I don't really understand what your problem is as this is the standard case (second element below the first one...) but i think your question is the media query that checks if it is portrait mode?

you could use `@media all and (orientation:portrait) { … }`